# Encryption in DATA access block

Tags: c#

I am using enterprise library DATA access block in my application and now I want to encrypt the connection string and store it in the config file and consume it in my application after decrypting the same.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt sections of your web.config using DPAPI provider. Nothing else need to change in your application. you still keep reading appsettings and conn. strings as usual.

```
//call: ProtectSection("appSettings","DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
private void ProtectSection(string sectionName, string provider)
{
    Configuration config =
        WebConfigurationManager.
            OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);

    ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(sectionName);

    if (section != null && !section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
        config.Save();
    }
}

//call: UnProtectSection("appSettings");
private void UnProtectSection(string sectionName)
{
    Configuration config =
        WebConfigurationManager.
            OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);

    ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(sectionName);

    if (section != null && section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
        config.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i am implementing this, but when unprotecting should i save the file in the server????

Comment: what do u mean by "save file to server" ?

Comment: Yes. you need to do this on server.

Comment: but what i observed is, i saved the config file after encrypting using ProtectSection function and when i try to consume the connection string without unprotecting it using Ent Lib Data block it is working :)

Comment: Yes, that is how it supposed to work. this works because configuration runtime detects that web.config section is encrypted using DPAPIProvider which means the config section needs decryption before sending out the values to user. You will see your <appsettings> updated like this -> <appSettings configProtectionProvider= "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">